# What's wrong with my program - short program

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, web, nan

Code description: A Car object updates its location and orientation regularly based on mouse location. I'm the requestAnimationFrame function for smoother rendering of frames.

Issues: 
The car object's x and y coordinates are NAN when I'm inside the drawing function.
Car doesn't show on canvas.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<style type="text/css">
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas">
</canvas>

<script> 

// requestAnimationFrame initialization with cross-browser compatibility 
(function(){
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();



// canvas and context objects
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
myCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
myCanvas.height =  window.innerHeight; 
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
myCanvas.addEventListener('mousemove', updateMousePos, false);


//mouse position coordinates
var mousex;
var mousey;

//constructor for a Car object with methods to update position, orientation, and draw the car
function Car(x, y, orientation, id, type) {
    //x and y are the cooredinates of the center of a car object
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.type = type;
    this.speed = 5; //default speed = 5
    this.isAlive = 1;
    this.stillExists = 1;
    this.id = id;
    this.orientation = orientation;
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.source = 'car1.png';
    this.img.width = 200;
    this.img.height = 100;

    //this method computes a new positin and orientation of our car. 
    this.updatePosAndOrien = function(){

        //caclcuate car orientation using mousex and mousey and x y position of our car using atan2
        var targetX  = mousex - this.x;
        var targetY  = mousey - this.y;
        var trgtOrien = Math.atan2(targetY, targetX);
        this.orientation = trgtOrien;

        //calculate new positon of car using speed and current location of car
        var dx = mousex -this.x;
        var dy = mousey - this.y;
        //distance between mouse and car
        var distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy); 

        //Now we compute xspeed and yspeed of car - which are displacements along x and y axis
        var factor = distance / this.speed;
        var xspeed = dx / factor;
        var yspeed = dy / factor;

        //set new positon of car 
        this.x = this.x + xspeed;
        this.y = this.y+ yspeed;
    };

    //draw method that draws the car on canvas
    this.draw = function() {
        this.img.x = this.x;
        this.img.y = this.y;
        this.img.orientation = this.orientation; 

        this.img.onload = function() {

            ctx.save();//save context
            //translate context origin to center of image 
            ctx.translate(Math.round(this.x), Math.round(this.y));  
            ctx.rotate(this.orientation); //rotate context 
            ctx.drawImage(img, -(this.width/2), -(this.height/2), 
                this.width, this.height);//draw img
            ctx.restore(); //restore context
        }   
    };
}

/*this function update mouse position upon mouse movement*/
function updateMousePos(evt) {
    var rect = myCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mousex = evt.clientX - rect.left;
    mousey = evt.clientY - rect.top;
    //log mouse position
    console.log("mouse postion: "+mousex+", "+mousey);
}

//defining car and starting the rendering
var ourCar = new Car(300, 400, 2, 111, 1);
console.log("car: "+ourCar.x+", "+ourCar.y);


/*This function draws everything using requestFrameAnimation(). */
function drawIt() {
    // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);

    //update orientation of player
    ourCar.updatePosAndOrien();
    console.log("car in drawIt: "+ourCar.x+", "+ourCar.y); //prints NAN for both

    //Draw car
    console.log("drawing the car");
    ourCar.draw();

    requestAnimationFrame(drawIt); 
}

//start rendering
requestAnimationFrame(drawIt); 


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: At `ctx.drawImage(img, -(this.width/2), -(this.height/2), this.width, this.height);` you’re using an undefined `img` variable rather than `this.img`.

Comment: wild guess: `mousex` and `mousey` are `undefined` wich leads to `NaN`s all over `updatePosAndOrien()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things going on here...

First, requestAnimationFrame(drawIt) runs on page load. If the mouse has not moved yet, then mousex and mousey are NaN. Furthermore, drawIt continues to call itself, so if you look at the console it just keeps repeating the NaN. I'm not sure what your objective is, but you might want to check for valid values for ourCar.x and ourCar.y and return if there aren't any set.

As for the image, first, like xufox said, you are using img instead of this.img. However, since you are inside a function at this point, you don't want to use this as it is referring to the actual img tag itself. You should set a variable outside that function and set it equal to this.

Second, in order to get the img.onload to fire, you need to set the src attribute of the image.

JS Fiddle and code below with comments and console messages to illustrate, and updates made to get it to work, you might want to refactor for your needs.

https://jsfiddle.net/2dd4rv9u/

```
// canvas and context objects
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
myCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
myCanvas.height =  window.innerHeight; 
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
myCanvas.addEventListener('mousemove', updateMousePos, false);

//mouse position coordinates
var mousex;
var mousey;

//constructor for a Car object with methods to update position, orientation, and draw the car
function Car(x, y, orientation, id, type) {
    //x and y are the cooredinates of the center of a car object
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.type = type;
    this.speed = 5; //default speed = 5
    this.isAlive = 1;
    this.stillExists = 1;
    this.id = id;
    this.orientation = orientation;
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.source = 'http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/black/car-xxl.png';
    this.img.width = 200;
    this.img.height = 100;

    //this method computes a new positin and orientation of our car. 
    this.updatePosAndOrien = function(){

        //caclcuate car orientation using mousex and mousey and x y position of our car using atan2
        var targetX  = mousex - this.x;
        var targetY  = mousey - this.y;
        var trgtOrien = Math.atan2(targetY, targetX);
        this.orientation = trgtOrien;

        //calculate new positon of car using speed and current location of car
        var dx = mousex -this.x;
        var dy = mousey - this.y;
        //distance between mouse and car
        var distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy); 

        //Now we compute xspeed and yspeed of car - which are displacements along x and y axis
        var factor = distance / this.speed;
        var xspeed = dx / factor;
        var yspeed = dy / factor;

        //set new positon of car 
        this.x = this.x + xspeed;
        this.y = this.y+ yspeed;
    };

    //draw method that draws the car on canvas
    this.draw = function() {
        this.img.x = this.x;
        this.img.y = this.y;
        this.img.orientation = this.orientation; 
        var self = this;

        this.img.onload = function() {
            console.log('DRAWING');
            console.log(this);
            console.log(this.img);
            console.log(self.img.x);

            ctx.save();//save context
            //translate context origin to center of image 
            ctx.translate(Math.round(self.x), Math.round(self.y));  
            ctx.rotate(self.orientation); //rotate context 

            // I set these to 0 because I didn't check the math and wanted to show
            // that the car would draw
            ctx.drawImage(self.img, 0, 0);//draw img
            ctx.restore(); //restore context
        }

        this.img.src = this.img.source;
    };
}

/*this function update mouse position upon mouse movement*/
function updateMousePos(evt) {
    var rect = myCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mousex = evt.clientX - rect.left;
    mousey = evt.clientY - rect.top;
    //log mouse position
    console.log("mouse postion: "+mousex+", "+mousey);
}

//defining car and starting the rendering
var ourCar = new Car(300, 400, 2, 111, 1);
console.log("car: "+ourCar.x+", "+ourCar.y);


/*This function draws everything using requestFrameAnimation(). */
function drawIt() {
    if (isNaN(ourCar.x)) return; 

    // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);

    //update orientation of player
    ourCar.updatePosAndOrien();
    console.log("car in drawIt: "+ourCar.x+", "+ourCar.y); //prints NAN for both

    //Draw car
    console.log("drawing the car");
    ourCar.draw();

    requestAnimationFrame(drawIt); 
}

//start rendering
requestAnimationFrame(drawIt);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.